# Can I get customer from order id?

Tags: magento-1.7

I can read all order id from the database using SQL query (it is required in my case). Now can I get customer detail by using order id?

I was searching the web but found something like this:

```
$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getEmail()
```

But I do not have order object, only order id. Also, above email id is not the one used by customer during registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you to get the related data.

```
$OrderNumber = "100000001";//Put your order Number here
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($OrderNumber, 'increment_id');
```

From the object of `$order` you can get all the data related to customer like Id, Email, First name and last name. If the required data is not available then also you can get the customer data by customer id.

Comment: Thanks Pavan, is this the email address entered by customer on registration or during checkout?

Comment: above answer was modified. It will clear your questions